# How to convert object of type Object to Long directly without typecasting it to other Object

Tags: java

What I want to know is can a given Object of type Object be converted to Long without casting it intermediately into any other type. Like:

```
Long lObj=(Long)someMethodReturningObject();

Object someMethodReturningObject() {
   return "1234";
}
```

I know about other approaches like casting it to String and then using `Long.valueOf()` , Wanted to know if there is some other approach directly. If no then why is it like that but for String plain typecasting is available.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - a `String` is not a `Long`, so you can't cast one to the other.

Comment: Check for regex/Pattern that matches only for numbers . If true then cast it to long. else you have to handle error message

Comment: You question doesn't make sense because, as @Oliver said, your code is typecasting a String, not a Object. One thing is an object's type, another thing is the object's reference type.

Comment: ... based on that, someMethodReturningObject could be called someMethodReturningObjectReferenceToStringObject

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache commons lang.Try whether it helps you.

```
  public static long toLong(String str)
```

Convert a String to a long, returning zero if the conversion fails.

If the string is null, zero is returned.

```
 NumberUtils.toLong(null) = 0L
 NumberUtils.toLong("")   = 0L
 NumberUtils.toLong("1")  = 1L
```

Parameters:
str - the string to convert, may be null

Returns:
the long represented by the string, or 0 if conversion fails

Since:
2.1

For your requirement

```
public static Long someMethodReturningObject(Object obj){
Long result=NumberUtils.toLong(obj.toString());
return result;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a less safe version of what the OP already has (silently failing rather than loudly failing).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following snippet of code:

```
Long.valueOf(lObj.toString())
```

Comment: This is exactly the approach the OP describes.

Comment: This answer is missing the point, the question was about other way instead of using Long.valueOf().